# JSON Object value assign to a multiple dynamically button

Tags: android, json

I am creating a Youtube Player app. I cannot understand how to assign a JSON Object value in dynamically multiple button. I am fetching data through JSON and the data convert into JSON Array. I wish to assign a Button background image, url video and also button name through JSON object Please help me ???

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    parent=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_parent);
    BackgroundTask process = new BackgroundTask();
    process.execute();
}
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String data = "";

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new 
            URL("https://manisheikh.com/hamza/Json_get_Button_Data.php");
            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) 
            url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while ((line != null)) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }

            JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(data);
            for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject JO=(JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                b1=new Button(MainActivity.this);
                b1.setId(i+1);
                b1.setText((CharSequence) JO.get("btn_name"));
                b1.setTag(i);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        parent.addView(b1);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain clearly what actually you want

Comment: Make dynamically button Through no of JSON Object

Comment: use recyclerview to load the data from json to your view

Comment: I'm guessing your real issue is that you create all buttons via a for loop, but you eventually add only the last created one to the parent view. You want instead to addView() within the for loop. But, overall, it's a very weird choice to add programmatically the buttons that way. You should instead separate the dataset and the UI views, using an Adapter, for instance like used in [recycler view example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Comment: I am already apply addView() function with in a loop but not working Apllication crash.

Comment: @HamzaAlam no you're not, you're calling it on post execute, and code does what you're telling it to do: it adds 1 button the the parent view, once. Debug your code if you don't believe me

Comment: @Alessio you can edit my code and send me please..

Comment: @HamzaAlam I don't think so. It's fine for you to look for help, which doesn't mean I want to do your homeworks. If you want to be helperd do like any proper coder, start to debug and start with something simple. In your case, forget the json part, and start with adding 2 buttons to the parent. If that works, make them a loop. Once that work, pass the values from the json. Once that work, go read about RecyclerView and Adapter, and re-implement everything with that design. Have a nice coding!

Comment: @Alessio ok Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    for(int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++)
{
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setId(2000+i);
    btn.setText(JA.get(i) + i));
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(view v) {
            // TODO Whatever you want onclick to do
        }
    });
    //Log stuff
    linearButton.addView(btn, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

**Note:- Don't forget to add view at the last**